# Webdriverio Selenium Standalone Service v6 onwards - unable to overwrite the hostname for private Selenium backend

Tags: webdriver-io

Webdriverio Test Runner has an option 
- if you are using a private Selenium backend, you should define the `hostname`, `port`, and `path` here.

```
hostname: 'localhost',
port: 4444,
path: '/',
```

Since version: "@wdio/selenium-standalone-service": "^**6.0.0**"
This "hostname" is unchangeable and always stay as localhost. It seems to autodetect that it should be localhost only and does not refer to config at all i.e. even if I update manually in wdio.conf.js as

hostname: 'selenium-hub',
    port: 4445,
    path: '/',

Upon execution, still the hostname stays 'localhost' instead of being 'selenium-hub' and port stays as '4444' instead of '4445'

In previous version the command line value with --hostname was getting overwritten successfully as required

i.e. ./node_modules/.bin/wdio wdio.conf.js --hostname 'selenium-hub'

would pass selenium-hub as hostname successfully....

anyone experiencing similar issue ?

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem? Did you find a solution?

Comment: Hi, I am using "@wdio/selenium-standalone-service": "^5.16.10"
to overcome above challenge.

Temporary measure but not sure how widespread this issue is - so not sure if it will get fixed or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add the hostname, port, and path to the capabilities array.

instead of:

```
 hostname: '{ unique ip address}',
    port: { port number },
    path: {'/'},
    protocol: '{http' || 'https'},

 capabilities: [{
    maxInstances: 5,
    browserName: 'chrome',
  
}],
```

Do this:

capabilities: [{

```
maxInstances: 5,
browserName: 'chrome',
hostname: '{ unique ip address}',
port: { port number },
path: {'/'},
protocol: '{http' || 'https'},
```

}],

Comment: Have you managed to overwrite these port and hostname via command line ?